# Can ASP.NET automatically generate code from an API definition file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, .net-core

On the Swagger page of many APIs (web services) there is a documentation file that includes information about API object properties (their type, whether they are required or not, etc.)  It seems this data could be used to automatically generate create/read/update/delete code or possibly code for an API service, for interactions with the API endpoints.

I was wondering if this is possible in .NET 6.0 (or other versions), Visual Studio Professional, etc.   Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it is certain that ASP.net can fully realize the automatic generation of API documents. It can satisfy your test of the backend interface.
Proceed as follows:

**1.    Create a Web API project.**

**2.    Modify the default API routing configuration
Why modify it? Because the default route of each Controller is assigned to "api/{controller}/{id}", the default generated controller is similar to the following:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebAPI.Controllers
{
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/<controller>/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/<controller>
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/<controller>/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<controller>/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**3.    We need a method to provide multiple HTTP access methods, so the action configuration should be added, such as: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}".
Modify the WebApiConfig.cs file.
Code show as below:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebAPI
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API Routing
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

**4.    Modify the HelpPageConfig.cs file, the code is as follows:**

```
// Uncomment the following to provide samples for PageResult<T>. Must also add the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData
// package to your project.
#define Handle_PageResultOfT

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebAPI.Utils;

namespace WebAPI.Areas.HelpPage
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Use this class to customize the Help Page.
    /// For example you can set a custom <see cref="System.Web.Http.Description.IDocumentationProvider"/> to supply the documentation
    /// or you can provide the samples for the requests/responses.
    /// </summary>
    public static class HelpPageConfig
    {
        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Globalization", "CA1303:Do not pass literals as localized parameters",
            MessageId = "WebAPI.Areas.HelpPage.TextSample.#ctor(System.String)",
            Justification = "End users may choose to merge this string with existing localized resources.")]
        [SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Naming", "CA2204:Literals should be spelled correctly",
            MessageId = "bsonspec",
            Justification = "Part of a URI.")]
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
             Uncomment the following to use the documentation from XML documentation file.
            //config.SetDocumentationProvider(new XmlDocumentationProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/XmlDocument.xml")));
            #region *************************XML display interface parameters and comments****************** ***********************            
            // Add the XML configuration of this project or other reference projects: multiple can be added
            config.SetDocumentationProvider(new MultiXmlDocumentationProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/bin/WebAPI.XML")));
            #endregion
             Uncomment the following to use "sample string" as the sample for all actions that have string as the body parameter or return type.
             Also, the string arrays will be used for IEnumerable<string>. The sample objects will be serialized into different media type 
             formats by the available formatters.
            //config.SetSampleObjects(new Dictionary<Type, object>
            //{
            //    {typeof(string), "sample string"},
            //    {typeof(IEnumerable<string>), new string[]{"sample 1", "sample 2"}}
            //});

            // Extend the following to provide factories for types not handled automatically (those lacking parameterless
            // constructors) or for which you prefer to use non-default property values. Line below provides a fallback
            // since automatic handling will fail and GeneratePageResult handles only a single type.
#if Handle_PageResultOfT
            config.GetHelpPageSampleGenerator().SampleObjectFactories.Add(GeneratePageResult);
#endif

            // Extend the following to use a preset object directly as the sample for all actions that support a media
            // type, regardless of the body parameter or return type. The lines below avoid display of binary content.
            // The BsonMediaTypeFormatter (if available) is not used to serialize the TextSample object.

            #region *************************Default JSON display interface******************** *********************            
            //config.SetSampleForMediaType(
            //    new TextSample("Binary JSON content. See http://bsonspec.org for details."),
            //    new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/bson"));
            #endregion

             Uncomment the following to use "[0]=foo&[1]=bar" directly as the sample for all actions that support form URL encoded format
             and have IEnumerable<string> as the body parameter or return type.
            //config.SetSampleForType("[0]=foo&[1]=bar", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"), typeof(IEnumerable<string>));

             Uncomment the following to use "1234" directly as the request sample for media type "text/plain" on the controller named "Values"
             and action named "Put".
            //config.SetSampleRequest("1234", new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"), "Values", "Put");

             Uncomment the following to use the image on "../images/aspNetHome.png" directly as the response sample for media type "image/png"
             on the controller named "Values" and action named "Get" with parameter "id".
            //config.SetSampleResponse(new ImageSample("../images/aspNetHome.png"), new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png"), "Values", "Get", "id");

             Uncomment the following to correct the sample request when the action expects an HttpRequestMessage with ObjectContent<string>.
             The sample will be generated as if the controller named "Values" and action named "Get" were having string as the body parameter.
            //config.SetActualRequestType(typeof(string), "Values", "Get");

             Uncomment the following to correct the sample response when the action returns an HttpResponseMessage with ObjectContent<string>.
             The sample will be generated as if the controller named "Values" and action named "Post" were returning a string.
            //config.SetActualResponseType(typeof(string), "Values", "Post");
        }

#if Handle_PageResultOfT
        private static object GeneratePageResult(HelpPageSampleGenerator sampleGenerator, Type type)
        {
            if (type.IsGenericType)
            {
                Type openGenericType = type.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
                if (openGenericType == typeof(PageResult<>))
                {
                    // Get the T in PageResult<T>
                    Type[] typeParameters = type.GetGenericArguments();
                    Debug.Assert(typeParameters.Length == 1);

                    // Create an enumeration to pass as the first parameter to the PageResult<T> constuctor
                    Type itemsType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(typeParameters);
                    object items = sampleGenerator.GetSampleObject(itemsType);

                    // Fill in the other information needed to invoke the PageResult<T> constuctor
                    Type[] parameterTypes = new Type[] { itemsType, typeof(Uri), typeof(long?), };
                    object[] parameters = new object[] { items, null, (long)ObjectGenerator.DefaultCollectionSize, };

                    // Call PageResult(IEnumerable<T> items, Uri nextPageLink, long? count) constructor
                    ConstructorInfo constructor = type.GetConstructor(parameterTypes);
                    return constructor.Invoke(parameters);
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
#endif
    }
}
```

**This modification supports multiple XML document methods, and the extension class is as follows:**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using WebAPI.Areas.HelpPage;
using WebAPI.Areas.HelpPage.ModelDescriptions;

namespace WebAPI.Utils
{
    /// <summary>A custom <see cref='IDocumentationProvider'/> that reads the API documentation from a collection of XML documentation files.</summary>
    public class MultiXmlDocumentationProvider : IDocumentationProvider, IModelDocumentationProvider
    {
        /*********
        ** Properties
        *********/
        /// <summary>The internal documentation providers for specific files.</summary>
        private readonly XmlDocumentationProvider[] Providers;

 
        /*********
        ** Public methods
        *********/
        /// <summary>Construct an instance.</summary>
        /// <param name='paths'>The physical paths to the XML documents.</param>
        public MultiXmlDocumentationProvider(params string[] paths)
        {
            this.Providers = paths.Select(p => new XmlDocumentationProvider(p)).ToArray();
        }

        /// <summary>Gets the documentation for a subject.</summary>
        /// <param name='subject'>The subject to document.</param>
        public string GetDocumentation(MemberInfo subject)
        {
            return this.GetFirstMatch(p => p.GetDocumentation(subject));
        }

        /// <summary>Gets the documentation for a subject.</summary>
        /// <param name='subject'>The subject to document.</param>
        public string GetDocumentation(Type subject)
        {
            return this.GetFirstMatch(p => p.GetDocumentation(subject));
        }

        /// <summary>Gets the documentation for a subject.</summary>
        /// <param name='subject'>The subject to document.</param>
        public string GetDocumentation(HttpControllerDescriptor subject)
        {
            return this.GetFirstMatch(p => p.GetDocumentation(subject));
        }

        /// <summary>Gets the documentation for a subject.</summary>
        /// <param name='subject'>The subject to document.</param>
        public string GetDocumentation(HttpActionDescriptor subject)
        {
            return this.GetFirstMatch(p => p.GetDocumentation(subject));
        }

        /// <summary>Gets the documentation for a subject.</summary>
        /// <param name='subject'>The subject to document.</param>
        public string GetDocumentation(HttpParameterDescriptor subject)
        {
            return this.GetFirstMatch(p => p.GetDocumentation(subject));
        }

        /// <summary>Gets the documentation for a subject.</summary>
        /// <param name='subject'>The subject to document.</param>
        public string GetResponseDocumentation(HttpActionDescriptor subject)
        {
            return this.GetFirstMatch(p => p.GetDocumentation(subject));
        }

 
        /*********
        ** Private methods
        *********/
        /// <summary>Get the first valid result from the collection of XML documentation providers.</summary>
        /// <param name='expr'>The method to invoke.</param>
        private string GetFirstMatch(Func<XmlDocumentationProvider, string> expr)
        {
            return this.Providers
                .Select(expr)
                .FirstOrDefault(p => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(p));
        }
    }
}
```

**Note: HelpPageConfig.cs needs to comment out the following code when XML document comments are enabled**

```
 #region *************************Default JSON display interface******************** *********************            
             //config.SetSampleForMediaType(
            //    new TextSample("Binary JSON content. See http://bsonspec.org for details."),
            //    new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/bson"));
            #endregion
```

**5.    Next you can write some Controller.cs. Then start the project to view the Api link.**

**6.    Configure automatic generation of interface test pages
Add a reference to the NuGet installation package:**

WebApiTestOnHelpPage

**7.    Click the "Test API" button to test.**